# Invoking a static swift function of an extended class from ObjC++

Tags: swift, objective-c++

I have a swift class containing a lot of methods. I've split it into multiple classes using the [extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) keyword.

Taking an example,

```
@objc
class SwiftModule : NSObject {
    
    @objc
    static func Method1 (_ pArg:UnsafeMutablePointer<NSString>) -> Void {                
        // Does something
    }

    @objc
    static func Method2 (_ pArg:UnsafeMutablePointer<NSString>) -> Void {   
        // Does something             
    }
}

@objc
extension SwiftModule {

    @objc
    static func Method3 (_ pArg:UnsafeMutablePointer<NSString>) -> Void {           
        // Does something
    }
}
```

Now, I have to invoke this method from C++ using the ObjC++ wrapper. I have the following in a .mm file,

```
// Include the generated swift interface header to invoke swift methods from C++
#include    "GeneratedSwiftInterfaceHeader.hpp"

bool CppModule::InvokeMethod1 () {

    NSString *  string;

    [SwiftModule Method1:&string];

    if ([string length] == 0)
        return false;

    // Do something with string

    return true;
}

bool CppModule::InvokeMethod2 () {

    NSString *  string;

    [SwiftModule Method2:&string];

    if ([string length] == 0)
        return false;

    // Do something with string

    return true;
}

bool CppModule::InvokeMethod3 () {

    NSString *  string;

    [SwiftModule Method3:&string];

    if ([string length] == 0)
        return false;

    // Do something with string

    return true;
}
```

I'm able to invoke Method1 and Method2. But Method3 failed with the following error

```
ibc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SwiftModule Method3:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x107343398'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This means that Method3 is not recognised as part of SwiftModule class, right? Why? Where did I go wrong?

I have seen a few posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897653) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478446/syntax-to-call-swift-extension-function-from-objective-c)) which showcase a similar problem, but it still doesn't work.

I'm using swift 5.0 and Xcode 13.4.

Comment: The code you shared compiles and works just fine on my end. Could you [edit] the question and include *exact text* of the error. It might be that unrecognised selector has nothing to do with the Swift methods being called, but rather with what is called from inside of the said methods

Comment: @TheDreamsWind, I copy pasted the exact error. Previously, I had only censored the file and method names.

Comment: Sounds about right. What is this `GeneratedSwiftInterfaceHeader.hpp`? Did you write it manually? If so, could you also include it in the question?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind, That's the header file generated by Xcode? Methods marked with the attribute '@objc' are exposed to the ObjC (and ObjC++) layers through the generated interface header. We have to include it manually (which is unlike a Bridge header, as it gets imported automatically in every swift file) and Xcode will generate it during the build time. The generated interface header has a particular format (ends with -Swift.h etc), but I changed it in the target's swift compiler settings.

Comment: Is the target a framework or a static library?

Comment: Originally I had many targets (static libs) and linked them all to build an app. But when you said it was working fine for you, I created an independent Xcode project (CommandLine tool), created a swift class and extended it....then tried calling the extended class's method from ObjC++ layer...It worked. No crashes. But in the big project, its failing, even though the syntax and everything else seems to be the same. Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: When importing static libraries, object files don't include Objective-C categories, it's a [known issue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1490/_index.html) which you can fix by adding `-ObjC` linker flag to the executable target (the target which has the libraries linked, not the libraries targets themselves)

Comment: Adding -ObjC linker flag worked. Thanks.
Put this as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When discussing the problem in details in the comments section, it turned out that the Objective-C interfaces generated were part of a static library which the final project is linked against.

There is [a known issue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1490/_index.html) with Objective-C categories inside of static libraries, where the categories methods implementation are not "glued" to their symbolic names by linker. In order to get it round you pass `-ObjC` flag to the linker in the **application** (not library) target build settings. It will make the linker to load all symbols of static libraries found in both Objective-C classes *and* categories:
[image]